# Image (instance) segmentation when the given masking information is partial

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, semisupervised-learning

In my problem, there are about 5,000 training images and there are about 50~100 objects of identical type (or class) on average, per image. And for each training images, there is a partial mask information that denotes the polygon vertices of objects, but the problem is there are only 3 ~ 5 objects per image with mask/annotation information.

So in summary there is 1 class, 5,000 * 50 ~ 5,000 * 100 instances of the class, and 5,000 * 3 ~ 5,000 * 5 instances with masking information.

So not a single training data image has a full masking information, and yet all the training data images have partial masking information. My job is to make instance segmentation model.

I did some search on semi-supervised segmentation, and to my understanding it seems like the papers are tackling problems where some training images have all the objects annotated while the other training images have 0 objects with annotation. That isn't exactly my situation. How should I approach this problem? Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: are there regions in the training image you know for certain there are no instances at all ?

Comment: @Shai yes there are. The four corners of the pictures and center of the picture is where we can be almost certain there's no object there.